# cant open article on homepage ( mobile version ) how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

cant open article on homepage ( mobile version )

site : unduhvector.blogspot.com

all code : https://pastebin.com/QQUEsywe

code post :

```
    <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Rx0l4ROAkck/XOrRJC0FDyI/AAAAAAAAACA/7MynWxLASqUQetiOnh3KqGXJGf_9PaQaACLcBGAs/s1600/it%2527s%2Bmore%2Bfun%2Bin%2Bthe%2Bphilippines%2BPNG.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="700" data-original-width="700" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Rx0l4ROAkck/XOrRJC0FDyI/AAAAAAAAACA/7MynWxLASqUQetiOnh3KqGXJGf_9PaQaACLcBGAs/s1600/it%2527s%2Bmore%2Bfun%2Bin%2Bthe%2Bphilippines%2BPNG.png" /></a></div>
<br />
Download Logo it's more fun in the philippines in CDR, JPG, PNG<br />
<!--more--><br />
<br />
Situs : http://www.itsmorefuninthephilippines.com&nbsp; <br />
Kontributor : @ykziruyhaw
<br />
Format : PNG, JPG,CDR
<br />
<br />
<b>Download <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s9arbKlb2zUPpv7n-nW6JX1Sw_IeTqpR" target="_blank">CDR</a></b><br />
<b>Download <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/15G5iqlMf-Qice1TueoWAnsf-n0cNVqyQ" target="_blank">JPG</a></b><br />
<b>Download <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EP0Vzacx4p8aT7wGjbIqFaBpE6rGzWqk" target="_blank">PNG</a></b>

<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Rx0l4ROAkck/XOrRJC0FDyI/AAAAAAAAACA/7MynWxLASqUQetiOnh3KqGXJGf_9PaQaACLcBGAs/s1600/it%2527s%2Bmore%2Bfun%2Bin%2Bthe%2Bphilippines%2BPNG.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="700" data-original-width="700" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Rx0l4ROAkck/XOrRJC0FDyI/AAAAAAAAACA/7MynWxLASqUQetiOnh3KqGXJGf_9PaQaACLcBGAs/s1600/it%2527s%2Bmore%2Bfun%2Bin%2Bthe%2Bphilippines%2BPNG.png" /></a></div>
<br />
Download Logo it's more fun in the philippines in CDR, JPG, PNG<br />
<!--more--><br />
<br />
Situs : http://www.itsmorefuninthephilippines.com&nbsp; <br />
Kontributor : @ykziruyhaw
<br />
Format : PNG, JPG,CDR
<br />
<br />
<b>Download <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s9arbKlb2zUPpv7n-nW6JX1Sw_IeTqpR" target="_blank">CDR</a></b><br />
<b>Download <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/15G5iqlMf-Qice1TueoWAnsf-n0cNVqyQ" target="_blank">JPG</a></b><br />
<b>Download <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EP0Vzacx4p8aT7wGjbIqFaBpE6rGzWqk" target="_blank">PNG</a></b>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you expand on how you're serving the webpage? What exactly do you mean by "cant open article"?

Comment: open the site unduhvector.blogspot.com via mobile, You see a post that can't be opened

Comment: Can it be opened on desktop either? I checked there first and couldn't see anything other than a [1], a sidebar with a few options and some logos?